# Wordpress - how to show links to 'private' pages in wp_nav_menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my WordPress site I have a requirement to show `private` links in the main navigation (via `wp_nav_menu`) even if the user isn't logged in (I just need to show the link, not change who can view the actual content).

I can do this elsewhere, using `wp_list_pages and` specifying the post_status(es) I want to display but I can't see how to apply that to `wp_nav_menu`.

This works:

```php
wp_list_pages(array(
    'title_li'      => '',
    'child_of'      => $page->ID,    
    'post_status'   => 'published,private'
));
```

Is there a way to do something similar with this?

```php
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu'              => 'primary',
    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
    'container'         => FALSE,
    'walker'            => new MegaMenuWalker
    'depth'             => 2));
```

My searches so far show a bunch of ways to post-process the results to filter out private pages (or drafts) using the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` hook but I have yet to turn up something on doing the reverse.

I suppose I could do a custom query to grab items that way but that wouldn't let me use my custom walker.

Tantalisingly there's `wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu, $args )` which does allow me to specify the post_status argument, however I'm left to apply my own render rather than being able to use the walker... unless there's some way to use the walker outside the context of `wp_nav_menu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wp_nav_menu` function **only walks through** the links in the desired menu and it's not fetching them. As can be seen in the source code ([`line 270`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L270)) the function that fetch the links get only the name/id/etc. of the menu and not any other arguments.

From the [manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu):

> Displays a navigation menu created in the Appearance → Menus panel.
>
> Given a theme_location parameter, the function displays the menu
>   assigned to that location. If no such location exists or no menu is
>   assigned to it, the parameter fallback_cb will determine what is
>   displayed.
>
> If not given a theme_location parameter, the function displays
>
> - the menu matching the ID, slug, or name given by the menu parameter;
> - otherwise, the first non-empty menu; otherwise (or if the menu given
>     by menu is empty), output of the function given by the fallback_cb
>     parameter (wp_page_menu(), by default);
> - otherwise nothing.

Therefore, you need to add those privates pages to the menu using the WP admin panel or create a function of your own that fetches the pages and build a menu (please notice: not a `nav_walker` as it just use the data and doesn't fetch it).

Comment: Thanks - I'll see what it does if I manually insert the link into the menu. My menus are currently setup to retrieve all children to whatever depth is requested. Generally I will manually configure the top level menu but leave it to sort out submenus (otherwise you end up having to curate the whole thing which is a drag).

Is there any clean way to do your own data retrieval (i.e. bypass whatever query feeds wp_nav_menu) and then use the walker to render the items?

Comment: Yeah pages manually inserted into the navigation do show up this way. Kind of a pain to have to do it manually but better than nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Here is a short snippet to show Private Pages in the menu builder :

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_meta_box_object', 'show_private_pages_menu_selection' );
/**
* Add query argument for selecting pages to add to a menu
*/
function show_private_pages_menu_selection( $args ){
    if( $args->name == 'page' ) {
        $args->_default_query['post_status'] = array('publish','private');
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Add this to a custom plugin or to your theme `functions.php`, and you will be able to add private page into any menu.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of the accepted answer, Private pages *don't show up in the menu builder* by default. [Here's a way to get around that issue](https://gist.github.com/ethanclevenger91/c8b26b1c7b3bc5d482844913508e4b6e).

Comment: The linked code is good, especially the simpler alternative given as a comment. However to make this work from WP 6+ the add_filter funciton needs to set a higher priority:
`add_filter( 'nav_menu_meta_box_object', 'show_private_pages_menu_selection', 9999 );`